# What is the best practice for refactoring a static method in order to make it more testable?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Let's say you have a static method that looks something like this:

```
public static bool Foo()
{ 
    var bar = new Bar();
    //do some stuff here
}
```

This method as it stands can be a real headache to unit test.

What is the best practice to refactor this so that it can be testable, without turning it into an instance method or changing the method signature?

Comment: I've deleted my post as it was invalid for your updated scenario. You may find this valuable: http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/12/static-methods-are-death-to-testability.html

Comment: As an aside, this probably belongs on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @Chris: agree about StackOverflow or perhaps on that now-defunct "Developer Testing: Unit-testing and more..." site!

Comment: Developer Testing has been canned, which is why I put the question here.  I didn't think it belonged on SO because I thought it would be too subjective (hence best practice)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It really depends on what `Bar` is.  If it's something simple then your `Foo` method is already testable, you just need to specify your expectations and invoke it statically, e.g.:

```
Assert.IsTrue( FooContainer.Foo() );
```

But if `Bar` encapsulates, say, your database access layer, then you can't test `Foo` without a real database, which is why (thanks @ysolik), [static methods are death to testability](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/12/static-methods-are-death-to-testability.html).  Or, in the words of Michael Feathers, "[don't hide a TUF in a TUC](http://blog.lowendahl.net/?p=299)" (TUF stands for a test-unfriendly feature, TUC stands for a test-unfriendly construct).  If `Bar` is **indeed test-unfriendly**, then sorry, it doesn't work well without making `Foo` an instance method.  You would need to redesign your code first:

```
public class FooContainer {
    public bool Foo() {
        var bar = new Bar();
        //...
    }
}
```

When `Foo` is no longer static, you can invoke it on an instance of `FooContainer`:

```
var container = new FooContainer();
Assert.IsTrue( container.Foo() );
```

The next step is to extract an interface from `Bar` (let's call it `IBar`) and inject it into `FooContainer`:

```
public class FooContainer {
    private readonly IBar m_bar;
    public FooContainer( IBar bar ) { m_bar = bar; }
    public bool Foo() {
        // don't create another Bar, use m_bar
    }
}
```

Now you can [mock/stub](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) `IBar` with your favourite [isolation framework](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2010/09/10/2010-poll-which-isolation-framework-do-you-use-in-net.aspx) and test your `FooContainer` code in isolation from its dependencies.

Comment: See my answer for an approach to keep Foo static and even preserve its signature.

Answer (score 1):

What is the point of Foo? What does it do? What is a Bar?

It seems from your question that Bar is a class that introduces side effects, *or* Bar is a resource.

Either way, in both circumstances, without changing the method signature, you're hooped without going into the ill-fated world of pre-processor directives (#if test var bar = FakeBar(); // = bad).

If Bar is a class that introduces side effects: without injecting that dependency or returning whatever it affects, you're in trouble.

If it's a resource (Stream, DBConnection, etc.) then the only realistic options I can see is to:

1. Extract out an interface and take an
   IBar as a parameter like @azheglov
   says
2. Create a fake/stub that
   inherits from Bar and pass that as a
   parameter

What it boils down to is that you're likely going to have to change the method signature, reduce side-effects and not create hidden dependencies if you want to make it easier to test.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have quite a lot of options. I ran into a similar problem today and figured that it all depends on how hard it is to instantiate an object of type `Bar`.

### `Bar` is easily instantiable

If `Bar`s constructor doesn't have any Parameters or all of them are available somehow you may do the following:

1. Add a parameter of type `Bar` to `Foo`s signature (we will fix the signature change later):

   ```
   public static bool Foo(Bar bar)
   {
       // ...
       var baz = bar.Baz();
       bar.Quxx(42);
       // more stuff
   }
   ```
2. Create an overloaded version of `Foo` without the `Bar` parameter and let it create the instance and pass it along:

   ```
   public static bool Foo()
   {
       return Foo(new Bar());
   }
   ```
3. Extract an interface `IBar` and use it in the signature of the new `Foo` method. Use the compiler errors to find out which methods and properties you need to pull up into the interface:

   ```
   public interface IBar
   {
       object Baz();

       void Quxx(int q);
   }

   public class Bar : IBar
   {
       // Implementations of Baz, Quxx, and other stuff
   }

   public static class SomeStaticClass
   {
       public static bool Foo()
       {
           return Foo(new Bar());
       }

       public static bool Foo(IBar bar)
       {
           // ...
           var baz = bar.Baz();
           bar.Quxx(42);
           // more stuff
       }
   }
   ```
4. Use your favourite mocking technique/framework to test the `Foo` method. It is still a static method and you don't need to change its callers.

### It is really hard to instantiate a `Bar` object

But what if `Bar`s constructor has some weird parameters. Maybe we need to pass values we compute inside of `Foo`. I found the following approach to be quite elegant.

1. We need some way to invoke `Bar`s constructor in the production code, but want to supply some mock in testing code, so we have to introduce some indirection. Let's use the factory pattern and create a `BarFactory` that creates the `Bar` instance for us. We then pass the factory instance to the static method:

   ```
   public class Bar
   {
       public Bar(Baz baz, Quxx quxx)
       {
           // do stuff with baz and quxx, launch a nuclear bomb, etc.
       }
   }

   public class BarFactory
   {
       public Bar CreateBar(Baz baz, Quxx quxx)
       {
           return new Bar(baz, quxx);
       }
   }

   public static class SomeStaticClass
   {
       public static bool Foo(BarFactory factory)
       {
           // compute baz and quxx
           var bar = factory.CreateBar(baz, quxx);
           // use bar
       }

       public static bool Foo()
       {
           return Foo(new BarFactory());
       }
   }
   ```
2. As in item 3 in the above case we can now extract the `IBar` interface and let the compiler help us to pull up only the members we need.
3. Now we can extract an interface for the factory, too. The final code will look like this:

   ```
   public interface IBar
   {
       // IBars methods
   }

   public class Bar : IBar
   {
       public Bar(Baz baz, Quxx quxx)
       {
           // do stuff with baz and quxx, launch a nuclear bomb, etc.
       }
   }

   public interface IBarFactory
   {
       IBar CreateBar(Baz baz, Quxx quxx);
   }

   public class BarFactory : IBarFactory
   {
       public IBar CreateBar(Baz baz, Quxx quxx)
       {
           return new Bar(baz, quxx);
       }
   }

   public static class SomeStaticClass
   {
       public static bool Foo(IBarFactory factory)
       {
           // compute baz and quxx
           var bar = factory.CreateBar(baz, quxx);
           // use bar
       }

       public static bool Foo()
       {
           return Foo(new BarFactory());
       }
   }
   ```
4. Create mocks for `IBarFactory` and `IBar` and use them in your tests. You will have preserved `Foo`s signature and it is still static.